# Azure search, search by partial terms

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Here are two examples for search in the portal, where I would expect to get some results in the second search, even with one letter missing.

The search is in Hebrew language

The full term return some results,
[image: First search return some results]

The same term with one letter missing return no results,
[image: Second seearch with one letter less return no results]

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways you can search for partial terms in Azure Search. You'll need to decide which of the following methods will work best in your scenario. Based on the example it seems either fuzzy search or prefix search will do the job. You can learn about the differences between the these methods in the documentation.

- Fuzzy search: [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/lucene-query-language-in-azure-search/), [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/Lucene-query-syntax-in-Azure-Search?redirectedfrom=MSDN#bkmk_fuzzy)
- Wildcard search, specifically prefix search: [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/Lucene-query-syntax-in-Azure-Search?redirectedfrom=MSDN#bkmk_wildcard)
- Regular expression search: [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/Lucene-query-syntax-in-Azure-Search?redirectedfrom=MSDN#bkmk_regex)
- Index partial terms by defining a custom analyzer: [blog](http://custom-analyzers-in-azure-search), [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search)

Let me know if you have any questions about any of the above

Answer (score 0):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59888638/how-to-search-a-term-with-a-middle-dash-in-azure-sea) I solve this using a regex and change the GET by a POST request.

[image]